# Change the type of a column in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have created a table `my_table` with a column `phone`, which has been declared as of `type varint.` After entering some data, I realized that it would have been better if I had declared this column as `list<int>.`

I tried to:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ALTER phone TYPE list<int>
```

but unfortunately I am not allowed to do so. Hopefully, there is a way to make this change.

**UPDATE:** Assume that I make a new column `phonelist` of `type list<int>`.  Is there any efficient way to move the data in the `phone` column into the `phonelist` column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot change the type of an existing column to a map or collection.

The table shows the allowed alterations for data types

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information (upvoted). Maybe you could provide some information about the update?

Comment: Can you check this link https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader#using-stdin Support for collections