# Cassandra Behavior - when a column dropped and reinserted with different datatype - data corruption

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra, corruption

I am using Cassandra as database.
I initially had a table with column A with datatype as text, Now the use case changed and I wanted the table to list.
So I did the following things -
Wrote migrationfile where -
file1. I drop the column A with column type as text.

Query -
ALTER TABLE DB_NAME.demo DROP A;

file2. Alter table and add column A again with column type as list

Query -
ALTER TABLE DB_NAME.demo ADD A list;

Above approach I used by looking into articles and suggestions (also referred - [Unable to change/alter the data type of column in cql cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321164/unable-to-change-alter-the-data-type-of-column-in-cql-cassandra) )

After that I had simple script which updated values in column A for some records.

Will the above activity cause any problem to my table as I am using same column name / column again with new datatype?

So after cassandra scale up & restart,
Will I get any corruption in SSTable OR exceptions that may occur in cassandra DB ?
Or any other concerns that may rise?

Asking as my database got corrupted and I am not getting the reason behind it! :(

I am not aware or not getting why I am getting the below exceptions on Cassandra -

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Corrupt (negative) value length encountered
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.skipWithVIntLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:359) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.skipValue(AbstractType.java:456) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.Cell$Serializer.deserialize(Cell.java:249) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.readComplexColumn(UnfilteredSerializer.java:670) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.lambda$deserializeRowBody$1(UnfilteredSerializer.java:611) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.applyForwards(BTree.java:1221) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.apply(BTree.java:1176) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Columns.apply(Columns.java:384) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.deserializeRowBody(UnfilteredSerializer.java:605) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.UnfilteredDeserializer$CurrentDeserializer.readNext(UnfilteredDeserializer.java:209) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableIterator$ForwardReader.computeNext(SSTableIterator.java:153) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableIterator$ForwardReader.hasNextInternal(SSTableIterator.java:182) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.AbstractSSTableIterator$Reader.hasNext(AbstractSSTableIterator.java:378) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Need help / guidance regarding the above issue!

OR maybe is their any possibility that the issue is not due to my above activity?

Answer (score 1):

Dropping a column from a table in Cassandra doesn't drop the data. The dropped column is just marked as deleted in a special table, but the data for that column is still there; they are removed before sending a response back to the driver. So when you add the column with the same but another type, when trying to read data, Cassandra will use the wrong codec and fail to decode the data, leading to errors.

The actual removal of the data for the deleted column happens during the compaction process, so you can add a column with the same name only after you make sure that all old data are removed by compaction.

Comment: Agreed, in Cassandra it's best to change the name of the new column, or perform a full compaction after dropping a column.

Comment: One notice: also important to have in mind that if gc grace threshold is not reached, it will make persist this column tombstone even after compaction.